# React @loadable/component SSR with Redux Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

I am trying to use `@loadable/component` [library](https://loadable-components.com/) with React at the app that uses SSR, Redux and Router.

The docs gives an [example application code](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components/tree/master/examples/server-side-rendering), but it's without Router and Redux (no need to pass state and render routes). 
The file `src/server/main.js` from the example contains such lines:

```js
const nodeExtractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: nodeStats })
const { default: App } = nodeExtractor.requireEntrypoint()

const webExtractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: webStats })
const jsx = webExtractor.collectChunks(<App />)

const html = renderToString(jsx)
```

But my app's server-side JSX looks like this (**without < App/>**), I have provider and static router component wrapper:

```js
const jsx = (
        <Provider store={store}>
             <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                 {renderRoutes(routes, params)}
             </StaticRouter>
        </Provider>
);
```

Could you please tell me, how I could use `store` and `StaticRouter` with `renderRoutes(...)` and this `@loadable/component` so that my SSR work?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Evgeny, did you ever find a solution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @natterstefan, Hi! Unfortunately no.

Comment: 7 months and no answers. Documentation also has no mention of how to fit this around <Provider> elements. Crushing.

Comment: hi @Aid19801 .check out [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050007/react-ssr-blinks-when-starting-client) maybe it could help